# mongoose promise and callback function input

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have went through some basic work on callback function and promise. But when I see the following code, I really can't find where did that zzz term come from.

I thought (zzz) is gonna be a input to callback function. inside the callback function, zzz was never defined.

`return Dishes.find({}).exec()` is only execution which returns nothing. even it returns something, it will go to output of the callback function instead of input, which is (zzz).

sorry if the question is stupid, i just looked at this point for 2 hours and can't figure out... thanks

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const Dishes = require('./models/dishes');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
    useMongoClient: true
});
connect.then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected correctly to server');
    var newDish = Dishes({
        name: 'Uthappizza',
        description: 'test'
    });
    newDish.save()
    .then((zzz) => {
        // ??? where did this zzz come from ??????????????????????????????????????????????
        console.log(zzz);
        return Dishes.find({}).exec();
    })
    .then((xxx) => {
        console.log(xxx);       
        return db.collection('dishes').drop();
    })
    .then(() => {
        return db.close();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the save() method is asynchronous it returns a Promise, and chaining it to the then() method you entered the callback function and passed it the ‘zzz’ argument.

‘zzz’ is the newDish object that you saved.

You can use the find({}).exec() in any case to find all objects in the database and execute a callback with the results.

Comment: Hi squez, thanks for your reply. i think im kinda getting it. whatever is used as input [B] in    "A.then( (B)=>{...} )"     will just be grabbed from what we are looking at before this then action which is [A]. [A]=[B]